# How to determine, who to contact for transferring my Domain

Tags: whois, domain-transfer

My client's domain, `www.daccusa.org`, is hosted at `inmotionhosting.com`. They tell me though, that the domain itself, is not.

I've spoken with two different customer supports at `inmotionhosting.com` and they both tell me two different things. One says "I have to get in touch with `www.joker.com`" and the other one tells me that "I have to get in touch with `webhosting.dk`".

According to my *whois* search, the registrar is *Joker* and the name-server is *Webhosting*, and according to the control-panel over at `joker.com`, I don't have any domain registered, but I can however login with my information (e-mail and re-generated password).

[(WHOIS)](http://www.whois.com/whois/daccusa.org)

I want my domain transferred to `inmotionhosting.com` - which one (*Joker*/*Webhosting*) should I ask for the transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to talk to Joker, or "CSL Computer Service Langenbach" (thats the company listed in the Whois as the registrar). It could be that the domain was simply registered under a different account that you don't have access to.

The nameserver provider basically just "points" your domain to the proper IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted `Joker.com` in the hopes of a proper respond and service.

Comment: Good luck. Transferring domain registrar's can be a real SOB just because it's basically free money for them. Here's hoping they make it easy for you :)